# Open Ports at ISPs Gateway

Tags: network, vpn, router, ports, routing

I am working to set up OpenVPN access to my home network. To do this, I had to contact my ISP, because they had the necessary port blocked at the Gateway/Router that I do not have access to.

In my house, I have a Google WiFi system.

They put the provided Gateway in Bridge mode, instead of Router mode. This solved my problem, but when I ran an nmap against my public IP afterwards, a great number of ports (including vulnerable ones) were now listed as "open".

My question is, since I have the router in the house, and I have it set up to block all ports I have not configured to forward, is there any real risk here, having the ports showing as open at the Gateway?

Comment: I’m confused. You setup your router to block most ports.  Did you run a new external nmap after that configuration change?  What were the results?

Comment: Yes, as far as I’m aware, the Google WiFi internal firewall blocks all ports by default, until they are opened and forwarded to the internal network. When I connected my computer to my mobile hotspot, and ran an nmap, it still showed many of the ports open.